# Sending method empty list when it should contain 2 elements Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm have this code:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
let list = []
handle <- openFile "polycake.in" ReadMode
contents <- hGetContents handle
let singlewords = words contents
    list = fileToList singlewords
    n = head list
    list' = drop 1 list
    polygons = polyList n list'
mapM_ print polygons
hClose handle

fileToList :: [String] -> [Int]
fileToList = map read

polyList :: Int -> [Int] -> [Polygon]
polyList n [] = []
polyList _ [x] = error "Too few points remaining"
polyList n (v:y:list') =
let pointList = take (2*v) list' -- Note: list' may not *have* 2*v points
    points = getPoints pointList
    list'' = drop (2*v) list'
    -- Calc Perim Here
    --Just (under, over) = calcPerim (fromIntegral y) points :: Maybe 
(Length, Length)
    poly = Polygon { v = v, y = y, points = points}
    nextPoly = polyList (n-1) list''
in (poly:nextPoly)

getPoints :: [Int] -> [Point]
getPoints [] = error "Can't create a point (None)"
getPoints [_] = error "Can't create a point (Only One)"
getPoints (k:v:t) = (fromIntegral k, fromIntegral v) : getPoints t
```

But getPoints is getting an an Empty List. After all vertices are read in, the last pair should be the last call to getPoints but it seems like it's sending another call with the empty list.

```
    Polygon {v = 4, y = 2, points = [(0.0,0.0),(4.0,0.0),(4.0,4.0),(0.0,4.0)polycake.hs: Can't create point (None)
    CallStack (from HasCallStack):
    error, called at polycake.hs:54:16 in main:Main
```

Here's the sample input:

```
 2
 4 2
 0 0
 4 0
 4 4
 0 4
 6 10
 3 15
 10 1
 12 5
 11 19
 9 23
 6 20
```

Where the first line is the amount of Polygons to make, the first value of the second line is the amount of vertices in the Polygon and the second value is a value used in calculations. So 4, 2 on the second line means 4 vertices, taking the next 4 lines as vertex pairs. 6, 10 creates the next Polygon with 6 vertices etc.

I'm just unsure where the empty list is coming from to try and create the points.

Comment: Test `getPoints` separately, e.g. `getPoints [1,2]`

Comment: getPoints works, it gets the four vertices as it should be seems to pass and extra empty list.

Comment: `getPoints` doesn't work; indeed, it will throw an error for every possible input.

Comment: How would it be changed to not throw an error when it's called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The empty list comes from here:

```
getPoints (k:v:t) = (fromIntegral k, fromIntegral v) : getPoints t
--                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

An empty list matches the pattern `t`. (Any list at all matches the pattern `t`.)

How you fix it is up to you, but probably the simplest fix (and also a quite reasonable one) is to replace your base case:

```
getPoints [] = []
```